# Changing color of image in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Recently I started exploring fabric.js. I want to change the color of an image by selecting a color from color picker.

I started by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206936/change-png-image-color-in-fabric-js). Exploring the documentation of fabric.js I deduced (I might be wrong) that fabric uses the HSL color model. The problem is everywhere I search, the range of hue is given between 0 to 360 degrees but the [HueRotation filter](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.HueRotation.html) in fabric expects values to be between -1 to 1. In order to solve this I calculated `sin` of hue to bring it between -1 and 1 but that changes the colour all together.

It would be great if somebody points out what I am missing. I am using [this code](https://css-tricks.com/converting-color-spaces-in-javascript/#article-header-id-9) to convert HEX to HSL. The only difference is I calculate sin of hue by `Math.sin(h * Math.PI/180)` to get it into range of -1 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If this library expects a normalized range equivalent to [-180º, 180º] or [-π, π], you can't resolve it with sine or cosine. Both functions can give the same result for different angles (sin(45) == sin(135)) while those angles represent different hues (yellow and lime green).

You can convert your input to [-180º, 180º] range first:

```
hue = hue % 360; //handle inputs greater than 360 degrees
let displacedHue = (hue > 180) ? hue - 360 : hue
```

Then you normalize it to [-1, 1]:

```
let normalizedHue = displacedHue/180
```